# How to call web service programmatically from Silverlight?

Tags: c#, web-services, silverlight

I'am trying to access WebService from Silverlight and call some its method.

I tried to use example from:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/394436/Calling-a-webservice-programmatically

```
// In Silverlight it is not posible to use this 
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

But it is not applicable for Silverlight application. Do you have any example how to connect to WebService from Silverlight and then call its method?

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight doesn't allow you to perform IO task synchronously to keep your application responsive. That's why `GetResponse()` ist not available. You need to get the response asynchronously:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(/* URI */);
request.BeginGetResponse(HandleResponse, request);
```

The delegate you pass to the method will be invoked when the repsonse is available. Example implementation of this method:

```
private void HandleResponse(IAsyncResult result)
{
  WebRequest request = (WebRequest)(result.AsyncState);

  using (var response = request.EndGetResponse(result))
  {
    // do something with the response
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gene! But how to call certain method from WS?

Comment: That depends on the kind of webservice you're invoking. If it's a REST-based webservice, just adjust the URI to match the signature of the method.